# Prove $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}:x^2+y^2+z^2=3\}$ is compact set

Tags: metric-spaces

Prove $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}:x^2+y^2+z^2=3\}$ is compact set

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have tried C is compact set and find Contact results but failed

Comment: Hint: If you could find a surjective continuous map $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]^2$, how would that help you? Do you know such a map?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I found the $f$ mapping but still don't understand what you mean

Comment: The beautiful answer of Robert Israel shows you what to do :)

Comment: Just try to find a surjective continuous map $g:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow S^2$ (where by $S^2$ I mean the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$). Then $g\circ f$ produces the unit sphere and its complement is not connected.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Why "the unit sphere and its complement is not connected" ?

Comment: The complement of the unit sphere $\mathbb{R}^3 \S^2$ is clearly not connected. Use the very definition of being connected and write it as the disjoint union of open sets (there is one obvious choice).

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  The unit sphere, for example, is the image of $[0,1]$ under a continuous mapping.  You can construct it using a [space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. I tried to prove it $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus$ unit sphers is it connected

Comment: It is not connected, because it is the union of two disjoint open sets: the inside of the sphere and the outside.

Comment: One more problem I have is finding a f continuous mapping: $[0,1] to$ unit sphers. Your link is $[0,1]\to$ unit ball, so i don't know mean you

Comment: You can wrap a ball using a square sheet of paper.  That is, there is a continuous map  from $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ onto the unit sphere.  So map $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ by a space-filling curve, then map that onto the unit sphere.

Comment: I have an idea as follows: Theorem: for all compact set is continuous image of Cantor set. Unit sphere is compact set, so have f continous mapping: Cantor to unit sphere. You think my idea  is true or not. I meet a problem is f just from Cantor to unit sphere but i don't sure can extend f from [0,1] to unit sphere. Hope you help

Comment: If you want an explicit map from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ onto the unit sphere, use $(x,y) \mapsto (\sin(\pi x)\cos(2\pi y), \sin(\pi x) \sin(2\pi y), \cos(\pi x))$.